# change IP range address

Tags: python, ip

I have a script that performs a scan through

```
    def IPsRange(start='', end=''):
        if not start and not end:
            return []
        if not end and start.__contains__("-"):
            start, end = start.split("-")
        end = end.replace("\n","")
        start = int(ip_address(start).packed.hex(), 16)
        end = int(ip_address(end).packed.hex(), 16)
        return [ip_address(ip).exploded for ip in range(start, end)]
```

The ip range is in the format xxx.xxx.xxx.x-xxx.xxx.xxx.x and I was looking to change it to xxx.xxx.xxx.0/24

Can someone explain me how to change this?

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved something like this:

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> def get_all_ips_by_subnet(subnet):
...   l = [*map(str, ipaddress.IPv4Network(subnet, strict=False))]
...   return l
...
>>> l = get_all_ips_by_subnet("172.17.20.30/30")
>>> l
['172.17.20.28', '172.17.20.29', '172.17.20.30', '172.17.20.31']
```

[ipaddress module](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/ipaddress.html)